# Either/Or-Arguments in R functions

Tags: r, function, arguments

I am still new in writing function in R.

I try to write a function that requires:
EITHER an argument "a", OR arguments "b" and "c" together.

Additionally this function has some arguments with default values.

How can I handle the either/or- arguments best. If "a" is provided
I don't need "b" and "c" and vice versa, but at least one is needed.

Furthermore "a" is a string (fruits like "Apple", "Pear" etc.) , while "b" and "c" are values. There is dataframe in the background where for each fruit the value "b" and "c" are defined. So using the function would either need a valid fruit (argument "a") or the values "b" and "c" itself.

The function I started with:

```
f <- function(a,b,c,d=1,e=2)
```

Comment: Perhaps the simplest way to go is to toss some `if(missing(a)){if(missing(b) | missing(c)) [do something useful]}` code into the start of your function.   Important side note: Avoid using "c" as a variable name because of conflict with the builtin `c()` function.

Answer (score 3):

```
 dfrm <- data.frame(a=LETTERS[1:3], 
        b=letters[1:3], 
        c=letters[5:7], 
        res=c("one", "two", "three") )
 dfrm
#
  a b c   res
1 A a e   one
2 B b f   two
3 C c g three

 f <- function(a=NA,b=NA,c=NA,d=1,e=2){ 
                if ( is.na(a) & (is.na(b) | is.na(c) ) ) {stop()}
                if (!is.na(a) ) { dfrm[dfrm[[1]]==a, ] 
                       # returns rows where 1st col equals `a`-value
                                   } else {
                                     dfrm[ dfrm[[2]]==b & dfrm[[3]] == c , ]
                       #returns rows where 2nd and 3rd cols match `b` and `c` vals
                                           }
 }
 f("A")
#
  a b c res
1 A a e one

 f(b="a", c="e")
#
  a b c res
1 A a e one

 f()
#Error in f() :
```

I think there might be some untested edge cases, but it's really the questioner's responsibility to provide proper testing materials and @Johannes didn't even provide a simple test data structure much less a set of edge cases.

Comment: I stared at that a while trying to figure out where it was not self-documenting and decided the only possible ambiguity was in the use of dfrm[[n]] to select columns.

Comment: And it that was your downvote, then I think you are not really following the SO guidelines. Downvotes are for incorrect or not useful replies. You can report code only answers to the moderator overlords if you think the code needs further explanation. On the other hand there is no review of downvotes and you cna do it any time you feel offended or out of sorts.

Answer (score 1):

The `missing` function should help:

```
f <- function(a,b,c,d=1,e=2) {
     if (missing(a)) {
         # use b and c
         b+c # you'll get an error here if b or c wasn't specified
     } else {
         # use a
         nchar(a)
     }
}

f('foo')    # 3
f(b=2, c=4) # 6
f(d=3)      # Error in b + c : 'b' is missing
```

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - No, `nchar(a)` is only executed if `a` is *not* missing.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the definition here of polar() for a good though simpler example:

http://blog.moertel.com/articles/2006/01/20/wondrous-oddities-rs-function-call-semantics

Comment: I just updated my question (see above) as my arguments are not directly transferable from one to another like in the polar example with a simple mathematical function. My arguments are strings and values.